# How to start a download using php

Tags: php

I have spent a couple of day's looking for a solution to start a download using php, of course I did find loads of solutions. Unfortunately none of them worked for me. For whatever reason when I test it and try to start the download, it does show the file I want but when I download it regardless of what kind of file it was meant to download it would download as a text file with my website's HTML within it.

Here is an example of one of the many examples I have tried:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($File));
header("Connection: close");
```

Comment: Anything that is output after the headers are sent will be part of the downloaded file. If your site is loading html in the download script, then yes, it will be included with the download.

Comment: `application/force-download` doesn't force a download. The `Content-Disposition` should take care of that. You probably want a valid content-type though like `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this please? You need `readfile()` function.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Note `ob_clean()` and `flush()` ensure the buffer is empty before you start the download, and be certain that no other content is emitted before you start the download. Look particularly for blank lines.

Comment: Thank you very much Ozkan Ozlu, that worked perfectly. :D. You've been very helpful and I'm extremely grateful.

Comment: `ob_flush()` can output a Warning if you don't have a buffer initialized, so does `flush()`, besides it doesn't ensure anything at all. I don't think any of those functions should be called to send a file unless you are sure of their purpose there regarding your project's design.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to serve files with PHP, hand it off to the server with `x-sendfile` headers. Performance is a lot better (especially for large files) and the server will handle the necessary response headers.

There is an [Apache mod](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) and it's built into Lighttpd and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) (with a slightly different name).